# when one field is filled other fields must be required

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I created a form.In that i added validations.if one field in the form is filled,all other fields must be filled or if none of the fields are filled then no need of checking validations.
  Iam using a method focus to add validations.once selecting a field,all fields are required validation executing.

iam using jquery-validation

```
 <script>

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#myFormId").validate(
            {

            }
    );

    $('.contact1').focus(function () {
        $('.contact1').addClass("required");
    });
    $('.contact2').focus(function () {
        $('.contact2').addClass("required");
    });



});
    </script>
```

when i clicking on the field required is adding to field.how to remove required if no field is filled  in the form

Comment: let's say you have a var validation which is set to true/false on your validation format. then you can set/unset require by that filed

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#myFormId').on('change', function() { // change or input event
  var $inputs = $(this).find(':input:not(:submit)');
  var anyInputChanged = !!$inputs.filter(function() {
    return this.value !== this.defaultValue;
  }).length;
  $inputs.toggleClass('required', anyInputChanged);
});
```

```css
.required {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myFormId">
  <input>
  <input>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

You could toggle required class if any input in form has no more its default value:

```
$('#myFormId').on('change', function() { // change or input event
  var $inputs = $(this).find(':input:not(:submit)');
  var anyInputChanged = !!$inputs.filter(function() {
    return this.value !== this.defaultValue;
  }).length;
  $inputs.toggleClass('required', anyInputChanged);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're code doesn't quite match up with what you want to do, it could look more like this:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#myFormId").validate(
        {
            ...
        }
    );

    $('#myFormId input').on('focus keyup', function() {
        if($(this).val().length > 0){
            $('#myFormId input').attr("required",true);
        }
        else{
            $('#myFormId input').attr("required",false);
        }
    });

    });
</script>
```

Also, you may need to re-call the validate function on the form when you alter the attributes (but don't quote me on that).

This should be closer to what you want, but have a play around!